# Enhance csv file database import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I'm using the script below to import a large csv file to my database.

If the table is empty the process takes about 5 minutes to finish on a local machine.

If I'm using the file to update existing values on the same table it takes more than 15 minutes to finish.

My csv file contains about 35,000 rows.

How can I speed up the process?

```
    if ( $request->get( $_POST["action"] ) == "import" ) {

        $file = $upload->file_upload( "import", "media/import" );
        if ( file_exists( DIR_UPLOAD_PHOTO . "/media/import/" . $file ) ) {

            $file   = DIR_UPLOAD_PHOTO . "/media/import/" . $file;
            $handle = fopen( $file, "r" );

            if ( $handle ) {
                $lines = explode( "\r", fread( $handle, filesize( $file ) ) );
            }

            $total_array = count( $array );

            $x = 0;

            foreach ( $lines as $line ) {

                if ( $x >= 1 ) {
                    $data = explode( "|", $line );

                    $titlu          = trim( addslashes( $data[0] ) );
                    $alias          = $this->generate_seo_link( $titlu );
                    $gramaj         = trim( $data[1] );
                    $greutate       = trim( $data[2] );
                    $pret_total     = trim( $data[3] );
                    $pret_redus     = trim( $data[4] );
                    $poza           = trim( $data[5] );
                    $pret_unitar    = trim( $data[6] );
                    $categorie      = trim( $data[7] );
                    $brand          = trim( addslashes( $data[8] ) );
                    $descriere      = trim( addslashes( $data[9] ) );
                    $vizibil        = trim( $data[10] );
                    $cod            = trim( $data[11] );
                    $nou            = trim( $data[12] );
                    $cant_variabila = trim( $data[13] );
                    $congelat       = trim( $data[14] );
                    $tva            = trim( $data[15] );
                    $stoc           = trim( $data[16] );

                    if ( $cod != "" && $cod != " " ) {

                        $verificare = $database->select( "SELECT alias FROM produse WHERE alias LIKE '%" . $alias . "%'" );
                        for ( $i = 0; $i < $database->countRows(); $i++ ) {
                            if ( $alias == $verificare['alias'][$i] ) {
                                $alias = $this->increment_string( $alias, '_', 1 );
                            } else {
                                $alias = $alias;
                            }
                        }

                        $database->insert( sprintf( "insert into produse set
                            titlu='%s',
                            alias='%s',
                            gramaj='%s',
                            greutate='%s',
                            prettotal='%s',
                            pretredus='%s',
                            poza='%s',
                            pretunitar='%s',
                            categorie='%d',
                            brand='%s',
                            descriere='%s',
                            vizibil='%d',
                            cod='%s',
                            nou='%d',
                            cant_variabila='%d',
                            congelat = '%d',
                            tva = '%s',
                            stoc = '%d'

                            on duplicate key update

                            titlu='%s',
                            gramaj='%s',
                            greutate='%s',
                            prettotal='%s',
                            pretredus='%s',
                            poza='%s',
                            pretunitar='%s',
                            categorie='%d',
                            brand='%s',
                            descriere='%s',
                            vizibil='%d',
                            cod='%s',
                            nou='%d',
                            cant_variabila='%d',
                            congelat = '%d',
                            tva='%s',
                            stoc= '%d'",

                            $titlu, $alias,
                            $gramaj, $greutate, $pret_total, $pret_redus, $poza, $pret_unitar, $categorie,
                            $brand, $descriere, $vizibil, $cod, $nou, $cant_variabila, $congelat,
                            $tva, $stoc,

                            $titlu, $gramaj, $greutate,
                            $pret_total, $pret_redus, $poza, $pret_unitar, $categorie, $brand, $descriere,
                            $vizibil, $cod, $nou, $cant_variabila, $congelat, $tva, $stoc ) );

  }
  }
  $x++;
    }

   }
  }
```

And here is my incrementing function

```
  function increment_string($str, $separator = '-', $first = 1){
    preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $str, $match);

    return isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) : $str.$separator.$first;

  }
```

Comment: Probably more for codereview than stackoverflow

Comment: It is likely due to indexes that have to be checked and updated with each insert. You can use an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) to see what, if any, indexes are being used during the insert.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - why would indexes be **used** on insert? Why do people immediately think that every database slowdown is fixable by indexes.. The issue here is that there are limited I/O operations available. Mechanical drive can squeeze 300ish I/Os per second. That translates to 300 queries per second. If those queries are transactions that group MULTIPLE queries, then the HDD bandwith can be used efficiently. Basically, forcing the disk to flush 500 queries in a single I/O speeds this up. It's **nothing** to do with indexes.

Comment: In my experience @N.B. we have seen the problem in large databases with INSERT operations like this. UNIQUES and INDEXES have an affect on the INSERTS which is supported by many articles like [The number of indexes on a table is the most dominant factor for insert performance](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert)

Comment: Dominant factor for slow inserts is not utilizing disk I/O and bandwith efficiently. Indexing is a subset of using I/O, but it's not the main factor. These types of queries are optimized by wrapping several insert queries into a transaction and then flushing them to disk opposed to doing 1 by 1.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the less you do - the faster it is. However, many of database-imports are slow because of hard drive. Not because of CPU, not because of insufficient RAM - it's the hard drive.

Here's why: a hard disk operates in terms of **input output operations per second** - I'll refer to it as I/O. That's the number that manufacturers don't advertise. They advertise things like bandwith and burst read, those are mostly useless numbers - something like DPI for mouses.

A mechanical disk has relatively low number of I/Os available. That number varies depending on the drive, it can be anything between 100 and 400 I/Os. 
An SSD has much higher number of I/Os available, from 5000 to 80k (and more).

That means that mechanical disk can perform, say, 400 writes in 1 second while an SSD can do 5000. 
The problem with that is that database queries are usually small in terms of data (about 4KB).

If you do simple math - 400 I/Os * 4KB - you get the number of ~1.6 MB/sec. What it indicates is that you are spending all of the I/Os but nut all the capacity of your disk's bandwith.

That also hints that you could issue larger data writes per I/O.
In mortal language, it simply means that you should start a transaction, issue several INSERT queries (say, 50 INSERTs) and then commit the transaction.

That way you spent 1 I/O for 50 inserts. In turn, it's literally 50 times faster. If you were to use prepared statements, this becomes even more efficient because MySQL doesn't have to lex the query every time you send it.

I won't send any code because you should be able to fix it on your own. Also, your code is open for SQL injections. You have a few things to modify, and if you are not sure what prepared statements are - shout back.

Comment: I'm using a SSD for the main windows partition where the wamp is installed. Regardin the sql injection what should i do ?

Comment: You said you're using PDO already. You just have to use prepared statements, there's quite a bit resources on that. It's actually simpler to write that than the query you have in already and it takes care of everything for you when it comes to string cleaning. Also, I'd rethink the strategy of incrementing aliases or whatever it is, on every insert you're scanning the entire data set. That definitely contributes to slowing insert process.

Comment: Updated my question with the incrementing function for aliases

Comment: `"SELECT alias FROM produse WHERE alias LIKE '%" . $alias . "%'"`  - that one is a bad one. You're going to go through every single row because it's a LIKE search with 2 wildcards. If I were you, I'd solve the problem in an entire different way. I wouldn't increment the alias like you do. I'd just save it as it is, without any numbers. Then I'd make another column where I would store that number you're appending to it. Now, what you can do is index that column and avoid a LIKE search. You can create a trigger that increments the counter in the new column if such alias exists.

Answer (score 0):

Push the SELECT into the INSERT so that they are all run on the server rather than going back and fourth from the client to the server.